# Виды отладочной информации в PE файлах

Tags: отладка, pe

Существует несколько форматов отладочной информации. Меня интересует 4 наиболее известных: CodeView, PDB, FPO, MISC. В сети ответов не нашёл и решил задать вопрос тут.

Верно ли, что PDB - это тот же CodeView только вынесенный в отдельный файл?
Что кроме отладочных символов может содержать файл PDB?

Что такое Frame Pointer Omission?

Поскольку любая отладочная информация в PE описывается структурой IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY, что должно находиться в соответствующей директории отладки, если вся информация вынесена в отдельный файл (в случае использования MISC это вроде DBG, PDB - файл PDB)? Наверное есть какая то ссылка на этот файл?..

MISC - это какой то конкретный формат отладочных данных или просто обозначает то, что отладочная информация вынесена в отдельный файл DBG?

Comment: Вы хотите написать отладчик?

Comment: Нет. Мне просто интересно. В книгах найти информации не получается...

Comment: Я бы не стал задавать такие простые вопросы если бы хотел написать отладчик

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типы отладочной информации перечислены [документации формата PE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#the-debug-section), а также в заголовочном файле winnt.h:

```
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_UNKNOWN          0
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_COFF             1
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CODEVIEW         2
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_FPO              3
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_MISC             4
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_EXCEPTION        5
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_FIXUP            6
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_OMAP_TO_SRC      7
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_OMAP_FROM_SRC    8
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_BORLAND          9
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_RESERVED10       10
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CLSID            11
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE       12
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_POGO             13
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_ILTCG            14
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_MPX              15
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_REPRO            16
```

Из всего этого зоопарка наибольшее значение имеют следующие:

**IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_COFF**

Наиболее старый формат, предполагает встраивание отладочной информации в исполняемый файл. Поддерживает только ограниченный набор отладочной информации (соответствие строк исходников адресам в бинарнике и FPO, если оно применяется для файла). Такой тип информации использовали версии Visual C++ примерно до 2005, современные версии его не используют.

**IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CODEVIEW**

Более новый формат, он допускает как встраивание информации в EXE-файл, так и вынесение в отдельный файл (.PDB). Однако в современных версиях Visual C++ отладочная информация всегда вынесена в .PDB, и Debug Directory данного формата содержит только ссылку на внешний PDB-файл. (Отдельного типа записи "PDB" в Debug Directory не существует.)

**IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_FPO**

Если программа компилируется без оптимизации FPO, ее стек представляет из себя связный список, в котором каждый элемент содержит указатель на следующий,  так что отладчик может легко его обходить без дополнительной информации. Если же включена оптимизация FPO, указателя на следующий элемент не будет, поэтому для успешного анализа стека нужен размер данных на стеке у конкретной функции. Эта информация и включается в Debug Directory типа FPO.

**IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_MISC**

Ссылка на внешний файл .DBG, содержащий отладочную информацию формата COFF и/или CodeView. Файл .DBG аналогичен по структуре PE файлам, его обычно получали с помощью утилиты rebase, входящей в состав старых версий Visual Studio. Сейчас редко используется.

**IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE**

Некоторая служебная информация компилятора (для Visual C++ начиная с версии 2010 при сборке с параметром /GL).

---

Для иллюстрации возьмем программу, собранную Visual C++ 2012 в отладочной конфигурации, и изучим ее Debug Directory с помощью команды `dumpbin /headers`:

```
Debug Directories

        Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
    -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
    5BAC500B cv            3E 000167B0     5BB0    Format: RSDS, {A11BDEB7-1F5D-4BFC-8E80-CE407A215DE8}, 39, C:\PROJECTS\CppTest\Debug\CppTest.pdb
    5BAC500B feat          10 000167F0     5BF0    Counts: Pre-VC++ 11.00=7, C/C++=27, /GS=27, /sdl=0, guardN=unreported
```

Первая строка - запись формата IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CODEVIEW. RSDS - это сигнатура формата, дальше идет GUID, номер версии файла (для отслеживания изменений) и путь к файлу.

Вторая строка - запись формата IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE. Из надписи sdl=0, например, можно сделать вывод, что параметр /sdl (дополнительные проверки безопасности) был выключен.

**Источники**

[PE Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#the-debug-section)

[Generating debug information with Visual C++](http://beefchunk.com/documentation/sys-programming/os-win32/debug/www.debuginfo.com/articles/gendebuginfo.html)

[Параметр компоновки /DEBUG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=vs-2017)

[Параметры компиляции /Z7, /Zi, /ZI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=vs-2017)

[Walking the Stack Without Symbols and With FPO (Frame Pointer Omission)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2011/08/22/walking-the-stack-without-symbols-and-with-fpo-frame-pointer-omission/)

[The .dbg Files](https://technet.microsoft.com/zh-tw/aa297109%28v=vs.71%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: "_Если программа компилируется без оптимизации FPO, ее стек представляет из себя связный список, в котором каждый элемент содержит указатель на следующий, так что отладчик может легко его обходить без дополнительной информации._" - Вы имеете ввиду стековый фрейм. Вопрос у меня больше по FPO чем, собственно, по теме: FPO заключается в том, что в стековом фрейме не содержится значения EBP на момент вызова функции - т.е. указателя на начало локальных данных вызывающей функции. Обращение к данным осуществляется через ESP.

Comment: Закономерно спросить вообще зачем создавался такой как регистр EBP если можно работать без него да ещё и быстрее (в чём и заключается механизм FPO). Или можно поставить вопрос иначе: зачем записывать значение EBP в стековый фрейм если можно обойтись без этого, да ещё и оптимизация будет?

Comment: Как вообще это работает? Локальные переменные адресуются относительно EBP без включённого FPO (их адреса, выходит, занимают меньше места), и через ESP с использованием FPO? А смысл нам знать адрес локальных данных прошлой функции, если мы не будем его использовать?

Comment: @D.Stark Зачем создавался какой-то регистр могут сказать только те, кто проектировал эти архитектуры процессоров. Эффект от FPO описан на его странице документации: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kxx5t2c.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Поскольку FPO несовместим с обработкой SEH исключений и затрудняет отладку (не любые отладчики умеют читать данные OFP из Debug Directory), а выгода от него невелика, обычно он не используется.

Comment: "_Зачем создавался какой-то регистр могут сказать только те, кто проектировал эти архитектуры процессоров_" -- "_Или можно поставить вопрос иначе: зачем записывать значение EBP в стековый фрейм если можно обойтись без этого, да ещё и оптимизация будет?_"

Comment: Ну если спросить кратко, зачем нужно вообще записывать в стековый фрейм адрес начала локальных данных вызывающей функции?

Comment: Для упрощения отладки? Должно быть какое то функциональное применение наверное...

Comment: @D.Stark Трудно судить с позиций 2018 года о решениях в процессорной архитектуре, которая создавалась в 80-е годы. Кое-какие пояснения даются например здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579262/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-ebp-frame-pointer-register?noredirect=1&lq=1 (в том числе, связанные вопросы)

Comment: Если адресовать локальные переменные и аргументы от `ebp`, то они будут располагаться по фиксированным смещениям относительно `ebp` независимости от того, в какой точке процедуры мы находимся. Это упрощает отладку. В любой момент отладчик легко сможет просмотреть значение любой локальной стековой переменной. Можно адресовать от `esp`, но тогда если в процедуре будут выполняться команды `push` (например, при отправке параметров в стек при вызове другой процедуры) и `pop`, то и смещения локальных переменных относительно `esp` будут изменяться.